# How do I go back to the selected tab bar view controller from a modally presented view controller?

Tags: swift, uitabbarcontroller, segue, uistoryboardsegue, tabbar

[image]

From the tab bar controller I want to modally display 2 other view controllers (full screen). After I’m done with full screen 1 & 2 I want to go back to the
selected tab in the tab bar controller.

However, when I use:

```
Self.view.window.rootviewcontroller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

It takes me back, but "viewdidappear" doesn't re-run. How can I present the selected tab bar VC again so that “viewdidappear” runs again?

Comment: Why are you directly addressing the root VC? I'm not saying you shouldn't, but between your diagram image and the lack of other code, it feels... wrong... to be doing this. Maybe something is very wrong with your VC hierarchy?

Comment: I’m basically trying to do is similar to posting an image on Instagram. When your in the creation process, you don’t see the tab bar, but when you finish, you go back to your selected tab bar vc and the vc refreshes with your new post

Answer (score 0):

Instead of depending on viewdidappear to be called on dismissal of two full screen view controllers. I would suggest you delegate the task of refreshing tab bar content on dismissal of two fullscreen.

For example:

```
    //fullscreen 2 dismiss action
         func done()
        {
           dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
                  //here you can have reference to presenter view controller as delegate and pass your info to that delegate
                   var info = some info captured from full screen two view controller.
                   delegate.dismissAndRefresh(info:info)
                }
        }

//In Full screen 1 view controller
   func dismissAndRefresh(info: Dictionary)
   {
      dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
          //have reference to tab bar controller and pass the info to tab controller.
      tabBarControllerDelegate.refreshContent(info)

      }
   }
//In tab controller
func refreshContent(info:Dinctionary)
{
  //refresh your content as you are doing in view did appear.
}
```

This is not the only way you can try directly passing the info to tab bar controller from the full screen 2 view controller and dismiss both presented full-screen view controllers.

But fetching root view controller using a self-view window will cause a lot of problems when you view hierarchy changes, for example, some other controller being presented or some alert being displayed.

Comment: How would i delegate it?

Comment: Just check for the delegate pattern in iOS, you are holding a weak reference of the object, class of that object implements protocol you specify for delegate. if you share the source code, I may tell you the exact source code you are looking for. For example, table view uses delegation for cell's view and data.